# how to add custom properties or label/subject for azure servicebus topic messages when using apache camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel, azure-servicebus-topics

I am able to send message to a specific subscription of azure service bus topic using apache camel using example here https://camel.apache.org/components/3.18.x/azure-servicebus-component.html#_azure_servicebus_producer_operations. **But i cannot get the properties set up with my code**. below my code -

```
    from("direct:start")
    .id("producerId")
            .marshal(new JacksonDataFormat(String.class))
    .process(exchange -> {
    exchange.setProperty(ServiceBusConstants.SUBJECT, constant("test"));
    })
    .setProperty("subject", constant("test"))
    .setProperty(ServiceBusConstants.CORRELATION_ID, constant("111111"))
    .setHeader("subject", constant("test"))
    .setHeader("label", constant("test"))
    .setHeader(ServiceBusConstants.SUBJECT, constant("test"))
    .to("azure-servicebus:testTopic?serviceBusType=topic&subscriptionName=testTopic-subscription&producerOperation=sendMessages&connectionString=RAW(Endpoint=sb://blablablablbalabla")
    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Message sent to test topic ${body} and ${headers}")
    .setRouteProperties(propertyDefinitions);
```

as you see above i have tried with everything such as with "setProperty" and "setHeader" different way. i get below response-

```
Message sent to test topic "{\"accountId\": \"4471112323123\", \"url\": \"test.com\", \"status\": \"PASS\", \"statusMessage\": \"check if received\"}" and {applicationProperties={label: test}, CamelAzureServiceBusApplicationProperties={Label=test, Subject=test}, CamelAzureServiceBusSubject=test, Content-Type=application/json}
```

This is my producer code-

```
Test test = new test(uuid, "test.com", "PASS", "check if received");
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;
producerTemplate.sendBody(direct:start, test.toString());
```

I have sent a message through azure portal(ui) and this is what looks like the properties:
[image]

if you see "subject" is "test" and there is a custom property "test" that has value "test".

I want to see the same thing when i use apache camel to send it. Please help. Thanks

[image]

Comment: Camel 19 has been released today https://camel.apache.org/blog/2022/10/RELEASE-3.19.0/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it's not possible with the latest version of Camel, however it will be shipped in the next release.

Relevant ticket : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-18459

Code : https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/main/components/camel-azure/camel-azure-servicebus/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/component/azure/servicebus/ServiceBusProducer.java

And this is how it will look like :

```java
from("timer:foo1?period=15000&delay=1000")
                .process(new Processor() {
                    @Override
                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        exchange.getIn().setBody("{\"message\":\"hello\"}");
                        exchange.getIn().setHeader(ServiceBusConstants.APPLICATION_PROPERTIES, Map.of("prop1", "value1"));
                    }
                })
                .to("azure-servicebus:demo?serviceBusType=topic&connectionString=RAW(connection-string-here");
```

Comment: i can add now custom_properties but still not he broker property https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8eLn.png 
@ChristopheWillemsen any idea how to add that?